# A library to edit geometry in C#

Tags: polygon, c#, editing

For my windows application, I am looking for a method to edit vertexes and geometry of features that are stored in a SQL Server database. I just want a simple function for dividing polygons into 3 parts and so on. Are there any open source library for these functions?

Comment: I haven't tried, but this could help http://www.mapwindow.org/

Comment: While I love the FOSS solutions mentioned below I think [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.aspx) will give you solid functionality with the smoothest integration. It's got a descent API and there are [some folks on here with experience using it](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver.types).

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Geometry is probably the best choice if you were looking for C++ library:

https://github.com/boostorg/geometry

For C# I know you can use GDAL:

http://www.gdal.org/

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp

Answer (score 2):

For C# [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) is a great option. It's one of the children of the [JavaTopologySuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/), father of GEOS, Shapely, JSTS, ffi-geos... and maybe Thorin too.

I haven't tested on a real SQL Server database, but you could use it like this:

```
MsSql2008GeometryReader geometryReader = new MsSql2008GeometryReader();
MsSql2008GeometryWriter geometryWriter = new MsSql2008GeometryWriter();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind; Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MY_SPATIAL_TABLE", con))
    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            IGeometry geom = geometryReader.Read((byte[])dataReader["my_geometry_field"]);
            geom.Coordinates[0].X = 1;
            geom.Coordinates[0].Y = 1;

            byte[] outputMsSqlGeom = geometryWriter.Write(geom);
        }
    }
}
```